# For what value(s) of c,m is the line $y=mx+c$ tangent to the curve, $y=x^2+x+1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is a follow on question in a 16+ UK exam paper for the question Express $x^2+x+1$ in the form $(x+b)^2+1$ which is completing the square and I did with the answer of $(x+\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4}$.

Comment: Your title does not match the post content.  Can $m$ and $c$ take any value?  Do we know anything about $x$?

Comment: @AndrewChin Andrew, I have inputted the question in with all the information it states in the exam question. The title is the part b question that you move onto, the part a is the post context.

Comment: $(x+\frac12)^2+\frac34=x^2+x+1,$ not $4x^2+x+1$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Excuse me typo, mistake corrected

Comment: @NourAlaas : Then this is very poorly written.  Where else have you seen a problem presented as "part b in the title and part a as the body"?  If the problem is two parts, put both in the Question and then have a title that summarizes the whole Question.

Comment: @EricTowers Part A is completely irrelevant to my question, but it does provide a potential basis than may help with part b so if put it in the description. Again it may help not definitely.

Comment: @NourAlaas : You have one answer that responds *only* to the body of your Question (that is, only to part a).  If your claim is that you have not written confusingly, there is prima facie evidence that you are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

We need that the following system

- $y=x^2+x+1$
- $y=mx+c$

has exactly one solution, that is

$$x^2+x+1=mx+c \iff x^2+(1-m)x-c+1=0$$

and then

$$(1-m)^2-4(1-c)=0 \implies m=1\pm2\sqrt{1-c}$$

as an alternative by [completing the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square)

$$x^2+(1-m)x-c+1=\left(x-\frac{1-m}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{1-m}{2}\right)^2+(1-c)=0$$

which has only one solution when

$$-\left(\frac{1-m}{2}\right)^2+(1-c)=0 \implies  m=1\pm2\sqrt{1-c}$$

Comment: How have you come to the conclusion that is the solution, do you mind explaining the context behind it. Sorry I know, it may be basic math. I've just turned 16 and these are practice specimen exams for schools and this isn't exactly the work we do at school.

Comment: @NourAlaas If the line is tangent we only have one solution for intersection. That is the Delta for quadratic equation must be equal to 0.

Comment: surely if it's a quadratic curve, then the linear line would intersect it twice so the parabola would have two points of intersection. The same way it crosses the x axis twice, why wouldn't a line do too?

Comment: @NourAlaas We have three cases for the intersection of $y=x^2+x+1$ eith the line $y=mx+c$ and notably $0$ solution, $2$ solutions or $1$ solution. The latter case corresponds to the line tangent to the parabola.

Answer (score 0):

$m$ takes all real values.  The graph of $x^2+x+1$ is a parabola that opens up.  Its vertex has $x$-coordinate $1/2$, as found in the previous part.  For $x < 1/2$, the slope of a tangent line to the parabola is negative and becomes more negative as we decrease $x$.  There is no lower bound on the slope.  For $x = 1/2$, the slope of a tangent line is zero.  For $x > 1/2$, the slope of a tangent line is positive and increasing as we allow $x$ to increase.  There is no upper bound on the slope.  Consequently, there are tangent lines of every possible slope, $m \in (-\infty, \infty)$.

You can use @user's argument to find *where* the point of tangency is for any choice of slope.